# Multiple figures in one chunk with knitr and Rstudio 0.97 or 0.98

Tags: knitr, rstudio

I try to shift from Sweave to knitr but I am stucked with a problem to use multiple plots in one chunk. Here an example:
Let this .Rnw simple file (named Essai.Rnw). Of course only one plot is shown in the pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<fig=TRUE>>=
plot(1:10, exp(1:10))
plot(1:10, log(1:10))
@

\end{document}
```

I transform it to knitr format using:

```
library("knitr", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library")
Sweave2knitr("Essai.Rnw")
```

I edit the file to get this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<include=FALSE>>=
require(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(concordance=TRUE)
@
<<>>=
plot(1:10, exp(1:10))
plot(1:10, log(1:10))
@
\end{document}
```

In Rstudio global preference, I set Weave Rnw files using Knitr and when I produce pdf file using Compile pdf button in Rstudio, i get only one plot, not the 2 as I expected.

Here is my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 Patched (2013-06-10 r62935)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/C/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.3 formatR_0.7    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.1
```

Comment: Definitive solution !

I solve the problem.

I created this file part of a project in Rstudio and in the project option, this option was defined: Weave Rnw files using (Sweave).

I change it to (knitr) and now all is ok.

In conclusion, the option for project had priority over the global preference of Rstudio who was well defined for knitr.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the cause of your problem but if you weave it with knitr, I think you have to remove the `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` line.

Answer (score 1):

If I compile the following, I get two plots. Note the deletions I made. Your original code did not compile on my system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<include=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(concordance=TRUE)
@
<<>>=
plot(1:10, exp(1:10))
plot(1:10, log(1:10))
@
\end{document}
```

Maybe read about the knitr option `fig.keep=` about how your plots get integrated into the output.